# How to apply a gradient fill to different polygons in the same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I am trying to make a simple map of the world in ArcMap 10.1, and I have a shapefile with all the countries in it.  I have the symbology set to unique values, so the countries are all different colors.  I want to add a gradient fill, but I can't add the gradient to its symbology without going through every single country and editing it.  If I select Properties for All Symbols, it will apply the same color to every unique value.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, can you say what software you are using? This will probably produce better answers. Thanks!

Comment: It does not seem to be directly possible (by applying a color scheme) because the color scheme only changes the fill color, and a gradient doesn't have one because the fill is in the gradient pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround could be to use the transparency. You first use unique color values , then you create a second layer from the same dataset on top of the first layer, with a grey gradient and some transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/01/20/sun-glints-add-realism-to-your-map/) page. It simulates sun tinting with gradient fills and gives a step by step guide. This should solve your problem.